# To calculate the difference in two different merged queries - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

i am having some problems creating a query of my project.
I have created a software that cyclically (every minute) interrogates 3 or 4 devices and saves the collected data (people's incoming and outgoing) on a MySQL database.

This is the structure of my table:

````
```
+----+----------+----------+----------+---------------------+---------+
| id | DeviceId | ValueIn  | ValueOut | DateTime            | Status  |
+----+----------+----------+----------+---------------------+---------+
| 1  | 1        | 00000429 | 00000327 | 2020-02-20 11:59:23 | online  |
| 2  | 2        | 00000350 | 00000278 | 2020-02-28 12:54:12 | online  |
| 3  | 1        | 00000000 | 00000000 | 2020-01-25 11:12:13 | offline |
| 4  | 2        | 00000300 | 00000200 | 2020-01-10 08:12:54 | online  |
| 5  | 2        | 00000330 | 00000250 | 2020-02-01 09:00:54 | online  |
| 6  | 1        | 00000400 | 00000300 | 2020-01-24 18:05:54 | online  |
| 7  | 3        | 00000600 | 00000700 | 2020-02-10 13:05:54 | online  |
| 8  | 3        | 00000000 | 00000000 | 2020-01-03 15:07:21 | offline |
| 9  | 4        | 00000111 | 00000111 | 2020-02-15 17:20:01 | online  |
+----+----------+----------+----------+---------------------+---------+
```
````

My Query should return one row for each month (grouped by month) and each device with the most recent day of the month that have been collected by the software.
The same line should show also the ValueIn and ValueOut of the previous month: I will need it to work out the difference and calculate the monthly inputs/outputs.

What the table should show:

````
```
+----------+-----------+----------+---------------------+----------+----------+---------------------+
| ValueIn  | ValueOut  | DeviceId |      DateTime       |  OLD_IN  | OLD_OUT  |    OLD_DateTime     |
+----------+-----------+----------+---------------------+----------+----------+---------------------+
| 00000350 | 000000278 |        2 | 2020-02-28 12:54:12 | 00000300 | 00000200 | 2020-01-10 08:12:54 |
| 00000429 | 000000327 |        1 | 2020-02-20 11:59:23 | 00000400 | 00000300 | 2020-01-25 11:12:13 |
| 00000600 | 000000700 |        3 | 2020-02-10 13:05:54 | 00000000 | 00000000 | 2020-01-03 15:07:21 |
| 00000111 | 000000111 |        4 | 2020-02-15 17:20:01 | 00000000 | 00000000 | null        |
+----------+-----------+----------+---------------------+----------+----------+---------------------+
```
````

So, 50 people entered my DeviceId 2 in February and 78 left.
In DeviceId1 incoming: 429 outgoing: 327

Is it possible ??
I did some tests: if I have no < DateTime rows the query returns no results.

This is my starting query.

```
SELECT
    TodayAccess.ValueIn,
    TodayAccess.ValueOut,
    TodayAccess.DateTime,
    devices.Name,
    MAX( OldAccess.ValueIn ),
    MAX( OldAccess.ValueOut ) 
FROM peoplecounter AS TodayAccess
    INNER JOIN devices ON TodayAccess.DeviceId = devices.Id
    RIGHT JOIN peoplecounter AS OldAccess ON TodayAccess.DeviceId = OldAccess.DeviceId 
WHERE TodayAccess.Status = 'online' 
AND TodayAccess.DateTime BETWEEN '2020-06-01' 
AND '2020-08-31' 
AND OldAccess.DateTime < '2020-06-01' 
GROUP BY TodayAccess.DeviceId, MONTHNAME(TodayAccess.DateTime)
```

I thank all those who will help me!

Comment: Pictures of data are never a good idea. Leave that output representation as text, it was fine that way :)

Comment: I dount that four rows are going to be adequately representative of the problem in this instance.

Comment: @Strawberry You right, i inserted more rows to rappresent better my problem.

Comment: Your result does not show *one row for each month*.

Comment: @Strawberry it should returns one row for each month/deviceId. i edited my original post.

Comment: I would expect *one row for each month/deviceId* to return 7 rows (1,2,3,4,7,8,9)